# CWAC-Pager use like FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am using https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager

> There is another flavor of the ArrayPagerAdapter constructor, one that takes a RetentionStrategy as a parameter. This will eventually allow ArrayPagerAdapter to work either like FragmentPagerAdapter (current) or **FragmentStatePagerAdapter (future)**.

So how can I implement RetentionStrategy? There is not much info about that. It has two methods:

```
public interface RetentionStrategy {
    void attach(Fragment fragment, FragmentTransaction currTransaction);

    void detach(Fragment fragment, FragmentTransaction currTransaction);
  }
```

I have many pages in ArrayPagerAdapter, so when It works like FragmentPagerAdapter It is not good for memory.

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I implement RetentionStrategy?

Well, you can see the one concrete `RetentionStrategy`, named `KEEP`, in the code, such as [this block from v0.2.3 of the library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager/blob/v0.2.3/pager/src/com/commonsware/cwac/pager/ArrayPagerAdapter.java#L288-L300).

In theory, you can create other concrete implementations of `RetentionStrategy` that employ different policies. You would then pass in an instance of your `RetentionStrategy` to the appropriate `ArrayPagerAdapter` constructor.

In practice, I suspect that `RetentionStrategy` itself will need to be expanded to make it practical for you to hold onto the state the way that `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` does.

I sincerely hope that I will be able to turn back to these libraries and continue pushing them forward in 2015. My apologies for not yet having added this feature to the library.